# Android SQLite. Множественные условия запроса

Tags: android, sqlite

Есть таблица с 3 столбцами - id, описание(текст), должность(текст).
По условиям задачи, задается фильтр, который указывает, какую должность нужно вывести на экран. И есть такой метод:

```
Cursor getFromTableWithFilter(String table, String[] columns, String selection,
                              String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy,
                              String having, String sortOrder) {

    return myDataBase.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs,
            groupBy, having, sortOrder);
```

Я пробовал сделать так:

```
Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getFromTableWithFilter("myTable",
        new String[] {"descriptions"},
        "prof= ? OR prof = ?", selectionArgs, null, null, null);
```

Проблема в том, что такой подход срабатывает только если задано 2 значения в фильтре (а их может быть как 1, так и 5). Как сделать так, чтобы аргумент "selection" был не привязан к количеству в "selectionArgs"? Или же есть более правильный подход к такой проблеме? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решил так:

```
String or = " OR ";
String tmp = "descriptions=?";
String selection = "descriptions=?";
for (int i = 0; i< selectionArgs.length - 1; i++){
selection += or + tmp;
}

Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getFromTableWithFilter("myTable", new String[] {"descriptions"}, selection , selectionArgs, null, null, null);
```